# How can I use HTML character entities inside EL in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I want to use the [em dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) in a value attribute for an `h:link` component.

Here is my attempt (currently not working):

```
<h:link value="#{somethingHere} &mdash; #{anotherHere}">
    <f:param name="identifier" value="#{somethingHere.identifier}" />
</h:link>
```

This results in a `FaceletsException`:

```
FaceletException: Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 13]
                The entity "mdash" was referenced, but not declared.
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:394)
...
```

I know I can use an HTML anchor instead, but is there a way to do it inside an [Expression Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language#History) (EL) expression? What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Facelets is XML based and processed by a XML parser. The `&mdash;` is a HTML entity and not recognized in XML. Only the five listed in [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML), `&quot;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;`, are recognized in XML.

Facelets/XML uses by default already UTF-8, and HTML entities are basically a leftover of pre-UTF-8 era and not necessary in UTF-8 documents, so you could just put the actual character plain/unencoded in the template (provided that the editor is able to save the file as UTF-8).

In other words, simply adjust

```
<h:link value="#{somethingHere} &mdash; #{anotherHere}">
```

to

```
<h:link value="#{somethingHere} — #{anotherHere}">
```

If this isn't an option for some reason, then you could instead use a numeric character reference in the format `&#nnnn;`, like as one would use `&#160;` to represent a `&nbsp;` in XML. You can find the numeric character reference in fileformat.info: [Unicode Character 'EM DASH' (U+2014)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm)

> #### Encodings
>
> HTML Entity (decimal) `&#8212;`

So, this should do for you:

```
<h:link value="#{somethingHere} &#8212; #{anotherHere}">
```

An alternative, which should satisfy the exact error message more, is to declare the entity reference explicitly yourself in the doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY mdash "&#8212;"> 
]>
```

But this isn't the general recommendation/approach as you'd need to repeat this over every single XML file wherein the character is been used.

Comment: Could you expand about why isn't recommended the entity declaration in the doctype?

Comment: It would explicitly need to be placed in every single XML template using this character, you can't just put it in master template or so. I'd personally just put the `—` character plain/unencoded in the template. If it fails for you (Mojibake, etc), perhaps you'd need to reconfigure your editor to save files as UTF-8. Facelets uses by itself already by default UTF-8 to parse/serve XML files.

Comment: Understood, thanks again! I'll use the numeric reference, to prevent Mojibake for other developers.