# XML entities don't render

Tags: jsf, xml-entities

Using `h:outputText` I want to display a left arrow ← using `&larr;`. But it just doesn't render on the page (not even in the inspect element output). What did I do wrong?

```
<h:outputText value="Overtime (Remaining &larr; New)" />
```

[image]

Comment: What **does** it render? If there is nothing, your problem is weird. Of there is something, the answer might be correct.

Comment: It renders the text I posted in the screenshot. The normal contents of the string are there, but the arrow gets simply skipped. As I've said, it doesn't appear in inspect element.

Comment: Exactly the same text as on the screenshot: "Overtime (Remaining New)"

Comment: Inspect element is different than the source. it is interpreted by the browser. The real source is not!

Comment: I've posted the source in my question already. Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: Visibility is on the client, so I talk about the client html source, not the server-side xhtml source (sorry, that was in a deleted comment)

Comment: Is it possible due to a font that doesn't contain symbols like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root problem is, `&larr;` is **not** a XML entity. It's a HTML entity.

Facelets is XML based and XML has only 5 predefined entities: `&amp;`, `&quot;`, `&apos;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`. All others you might have seen or heard about are all HTML entities and not supported in XML.

Historically, HTML entities were used to support "special" characters anyway when using inferior character encodings such as ISO-XXX instead of UTF-XXX. But since the introduction and worldwide support of UTF-XXX character encodings, we don't really need these HTML entities anymore.

XML supports UTF-8, so just print `←` right away.

```
<h:outputText value="Overtime (Remaining ← New)" />
```

Or even without a whole `<h:outputText>` as you don't actually need to convert anything here.

```
Overtime (Remaining ← New)
```

#### See also:

- [How to use HTML character entities inside EL in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992707/how-to-use-html-character-entities-inside-el-in-jsf/)
- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything)

Comment: Ohhhhh... I didn't know there was a difference. Unfortunately, I cannot put unicode directly into the source, as our CMS has a history of turning those into mojibake. I've just tested it with <- `&lt;-` and it does the job, even if not as pleasing. Thank you very much!